# how to have has_many and belongs_to with another column than id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table Advertiser and Offer where an Advertiser has multiple offers.

**Advertiser table**

```sql
id
advertiser_id
name
...
```

**Offer table**

```sql
id
advertiser_id
title
...
```

I have my model **advertiser.rb**

```rb
has_many :offers
```

and **offer.rb**

```rb
belongs_to :advertiser
```

Therefore the relation is using advertiser.id and not advertiser.advertiser_id to make the relation. Is there a way to specify that the relation is made through the advertiser.advertiser_id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-primary-key

```
belongs_to :advertiser, primary_key: :advertiser_id
```

(anyway, I don't understand why your advertisers table has both an id and an advertiser_id, why are those ids different?)

Comment: I have this messy ID organisation because I scrap this data from a csv file and that's how the csv is setup. Thanks for your reply, I must have missed this while reading the docs.